# Setting System properties in JAVA LifeCycle Listener

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat, properties-file

I'm trying to set application properties from file in resources at boot time of tomcat. For this I'm using LifeCycleListener with `contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce)` method.
Currently I'm having 2 problems I can't overcome. First one is having null pointer of fileNotFound exception, when using `ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream("tapi.properties")`, even though file exists both in /src/main/resources and in /target/classes.

When I tried using `FileInputStream(absolutePathToFile)` I received some really weird error:

`SEVERE: Error waiting for multi-thread deployment of context descriptors to completenulljava.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NullPointerExceptionnull        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)null        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)null        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:597)null        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:493)null        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1713)null        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:337)null        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)null        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)null        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:388)null        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:333)null        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1136)null        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:819)null        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)null        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1571)null        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1561)null        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)null        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)null        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)null        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)nullCaused by: java.lang.NullPointerExceptionnull        at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:277)null        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.returnCanonicalPath(HostConfig.java:420)null        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.addGlobalRedeployResources(HostConfig.java:1378)null        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:753)null        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1966)null        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)null        ... 4 morenull`

At this point I have no more ideas what I can do.

Here is my code:

```
public class LifeCycleListener implements ServletContextListener {
    Logger log = Logger.getLogger(LifeCycleListener.class);
    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {


        Properties prop = new Properties();
        try (InputStream input = ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("tapi.properties")) {
            if (input == null) {
                throw new FileNotFoundException("tapi.properties");
            }
            prop.load(input);
            System.setProperties(prop);
        }catch (FileNotFoundException e){
            log.debug("File not found");
            log.debug(e.getMessage());
        }catch (IOException ex) {
            log.debug("Exception while loading properties file");
            log.debug(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

I'm coding in Intellij.
Please help!

Comment: Add a slash here: ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream("/tapi.properties")

Comment: Still not working.

Comment: try this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/tapi.properties")

Comment: Alright, now I found out that I was using wrong method - getSystemResourceAsStream() instead of getResourceAsStream(). Now I have only ```SEVERE: Error waiting for multi-thread deployment of context descriptors to complete ```